# Convert 2D array to std::map?

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, vector

An array can be converted into a `std::vector` easily and efficiently:

```
template <typename T, int N>
vector<T> array_to_vector(T(& a)[N]) {

  return vector<T>(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(T));

}
```

Is there a similar way to convert a two dimensional array into a `std::map` without iterating over the members? This looks like an unusual function signature, but in my particular situation, the keys and values in these maps will be of the same type.

```
template <typename T, int N>
map<T, T> array_to_map(T(& a)[N][2]) {

  // ...?

}
```

Here's the test code I put together for this question. It will compile and run as-is; the goal is to get it to compile with the block comment in `main` uncommented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, int N>
vector<T> array_to_vector(T(& a)[N]) {

  return vector<T>(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(T));

}

template <typename T, int N>
map<T, T> array_to_map(T(& a)[N][2]) {

  // This doesn't work; members won't convert to pair 

  return map<T, T>(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(T));

}

int main() {

  int a[] = { 12, 23, 34 };

  vector<int> v = array_to_vector(a);

  cout << v[1] << endl;

  /*
  string b[][2] = {
    {"one", "check 1"},
    {"two", "check 2"}
   };

  map<string, string> m = array_to_map(b);

  cout << m["two"] << endl;
  */
}
```

Again, I'm not looking for answers with code that iterates over each member of the array... I could write that myself. If it can't be done in a better way, I'll accept that as an answer.

Comment: You could write a custom iterator that consumes the double array, but would that be useful? It'd be a lot more code for sure.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm not sure it would be useful, I might as well just iterate inside the function. I'm wondering if there is some way to do it by casting arrays to std::pair or leveraging something else from the STL that I don't know about.

Comment: Maybe std::copy with a specialized insert_iterator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

```
template <typename T, int N>
map<T, T> array_to_map(T(& a)[N][2]) 
{
    map<T, T> result;
    std::transform(
        a, a+N, std::inserter(result, result.begin()),
        [] (T const(&p)[2]) { return std::make_pair(p[0], p[1]); }
        );

    return result;
}
```

If you have C++03 you could use

```
template <typename T>
static std::pair<T, T> as_pair(T const(&p)[2]) {
    return std::make_pair(p[0], p[1]);
}

template <typename T, int N>
map<T, T> array_to_map(T(& a)[N][2]) {
    map<T, T> result;
    std::transform(a, a+N, std::inserter(result, result.begin()), as_pair<T>);
    return result;
}
```

#### Full demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5bafcdf8793dd5a)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, int N>
vector<T> array_to_vector(T const(& a)[N]) {
  return vector<T>(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(T));
}

template <typename T>
static std::pair<T, T> as_pair(T const(&p)[2])
{
    return std::make_pair(p[0], p[1]);
}

template <typename T, int N>
map<T, T> array_to_map(T const(& a)[N][2]) 
{
    map<T, T> result;

    // C++03: std::transform(a, a+N, std::inserter(result, result.begin()), as_pair<T>);
    std::transform(
        a, a+N, std::inserter(result, result.begin()),
        [] (T const(&p)[2]) { return std::make_pair(p[0], p[1]); }
        );

    return result;
}

int main() {

  int a[] = { 12, 23, 34 };
  vector<int> v = array_to_vector(a);
  cout << v[1] << endl;

  const string b[][2] = {
    {"one", "check 1"},
    {"two", "check 2"}
   };

  map<string, string> m = array_to_map(b);

  cout << m["two"] << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I'll have to look into `transform` and `inserter`.

Comment: @sehe I clicked on the live link above and it directed me to what appears to be a randsomware popup.   Looks like the link is old and site was compromised without your knowledge.  Maybe better host the live demo elsewhere or remove the link as it seems dangerous.  I was looking for a solution to convert a flat table representation of a hierarchical tree back to a table (this answer you created looks promising but I was hoping to do it with ranges).

Comment: @johnco3 Regarding your question, feel free to post it (together with an example of what  the representations mean/look like; to me it sounds like "convert a table to a table" and I'm not sure what the question is :))

Comment: @sehe you're welcome the popup was pretty scary!  Actually I posted a question on SO and the answers are not quite right (if memory serves me well, you are a ranges or ranges-v3 person) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76511234/using-c-ranges-to-create-hierarchical-tree-structure-from-a-flattened-table) however the answers are not quite right.  I was hoping to  unflatten a vector of structs (table) into a tree like struct (map for ex) as 2 of the fields in the structs have a 1:N ralationship.  I hoped to compose an outer range that returns a subrange loop and the inner loop be a range loop.