# How to get associated function names with the imported library

Tags: linux, elf

if i have an ELF file, how can i get each functions imported from a library file ".so" , displaying that shared library associated with the function ?

Comment: You can probably use objdump or one of those type of utilities to do this somehow. Not sure exactly, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This works nicely for me:

```
nm -uC test
```

E.g. on the code from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12772722/85371) I just wrote:

```
g++ -O0 -I ~/custom/boost/ test.cpp -o test 
nm -uC test
```

The output is

```
 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
 U _Unwind_Resume@@GCC_3.0
 U std::string::compare(std::string const&) const@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::allocator<char>::allocator()@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::allocator<char>::~allocator()@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::ostream::operator<<(int)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::ios_base::Init::Init()@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::ios_base::Init::~Init()@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::__throw_bad_alloc()@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U operator delete(void*)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U operator new(unsigned long)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
 U __cxa_atexit@@GLIBC_2.2.5
 U __cxa_begin_catch@@CXXABI_1.3
 U __cxa_end_catch@@CXXABI_1.3
 U __cxa_rethrow@@CXXABI_1.3
 w __gmon_start__
 U __gxx_personality_v0@@CXXABI_1.3
 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
 U memmove@@GLIBC_2.2.5
 w pthread_cancel
```

I'm somewhat aware of the deficiency that this doesn't say which shared object should fulfil the dependency, but I guess a little join on the output of `nm` for those libraries should take you a long way.

*Drop the `-C` flag to prevent name demangling. This could be highly effective if you intend to do a crossreference on the data. Use `c++filt` to demangle names later, in case you want to present the names in user-friendly fashion*