# using C++ ranges to create hierarchical tree structure from a flattened table

Tags: c++, stl, treeview, std-ranges, range-v3

I have a simple struct containing three fields and a spaceship operator `<=>` as follows:

```
using MyStruct = struct MyStruct {
    unsigned id;
    std::filesystem::path sourcePath;
    std::string functionName;
    auto operator<=>(const MyStruct&) const = default;
};
```

The data is initialized as shown below:

```
std::vector<MyStruct> structs{
    {1, "c:/temp/file3.c", "chimp()"},
    {2, "c:/temp/file3.c", "ape()"},
    {3, "c:/temp/file1.c", "foo()"},
    {4, "c:/temp/file1.c", "bar()"},
    {5, "c:/temp/file1.c", "baz()"},
    {6, "c:/temp/sub/file3.c", "file3Fn2()"},
    {7, "c:/temp/sub/file3.c", "file3Fn1()"},
    {8, "c:/temp/file2.c", "file2Fn2()"},
    {9, "c:/temp/file2.c", "file2Fn3()"},
    {10, "c:/temp/file2.c", "file2Fn1()"},
};
```

I am trying to create a very simple sorted tree from the following 2 fields (`sourcePath` and `functionName`).  I do not care about the id field.

In order to create the tree struct, I need to filter out the unique filenames and then add the function names as leaves to these filenames.

I would like to use the new c++20 ranges or ranges-v3 to to achieve this but I am having trouble piping the right ranges/views together.  I need to break up the flattened data into 2 loops: an outer one containing filenames, and an inner one with the function names associated with each filename.

The tree I am after is:

```
├───root
    ├───file1.c
    │   ├───foo()
    │   ├───foo()
    │   └───baz()
    ├───file2.c
    │   ├───file2Fn1()
    │   ├───file2Fn2()
    │   └───file2Fn3()
    ├───file3.c
    │   ├───ape()
    │   └───chimp()
    └───sub
        └───file3.c
            ├───file3Fn1()
            └───file3Fn2()
```

This is the code (and results) I have so far (Visual Studio 2022 Preview 2)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using MyStruct = struct MyStruct {
    unsigned id;
    std::filesystem::path sourcePath;
    std::string functionName;
    auto operator<=>(const MyStruct&) const = default;
};

//! Template partial specialization for use with std::formatter
template<>
struct std::formatter<MyStruct> : std::formatter<std::string_view> {
    // parse inherited from std::formatter<std::string_view>
    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const MyStruct& arg, FormatContext& ctx) {
        return formatter<string_view>::format(std::format(
            "{}\t{}\t{}"
            , arg.id
            , arg.sourcePath.generic_string()
            , arg.functionName), ctx);
    }
};

void
print(std::string_view intro, const std::vector<MyStruct>& container) {
    std::cout << intro << '\n';
    for (const auto& next : container) {
        std::cout << std::format("{}\n", next);
    }
}

std::vector<MyStruct> structs{
    {1, "c:/temp/file3.c", "chimp()"},
    {2, "c:/temp/file3.c", "ape()"},
    {3, "c:/temp/file1.c", "foo()"},
    {4, "c:/temp/file1.c", "bar()"},
    {5, "c:/temp/file1.c", "baz()"},
    {6, "c:/temp/sub/file3.c", "file3Fn2()"},
    {7, "c:/temp/sub/file3.c", "file3Fn1()"},
    {8, "c:/temp/file2.c", "file2Fn2()"},
    {9, "c:/temp/file2.c", "file2Fn3()"},
    {10, "c:/temp/file2.c", "file2Fn1()"},
};

// comparator used for unique
static const auto customComp = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
    return std::tie(lhs.sourcePath, lhs.functionName) <
        std::tie(rhs.sourcePath, rhs.functionName);
    };

int
main() {

    auto copy = structs;
    std::ranges::sort(copy, {}, &MyStruct::sourcePath);
    print("after sorting by sourcePath", copy);
    std::ranges::sort(copy, customComp);
    print("after sorting by customComp", copy);
}
```

program output is as follows, note the order of the `customComp` comparator seems to produce the correctly ordered results.

```
after sorting by sourcePath
3       c:/temp/file1.c foo()
4       c:/temp/file1.c bar()
5       c:/temp/file1.c baz()
8       c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn2()
9       c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn3()
10      c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn1()
1       c:/temp/file3.c chimp()
2       c:/temp/file3.c ape()
6       c:/temp/sub/file3.c     file3Fn2()
7       c:/temp/sub/file3.c     file3Fn1()
after sorting by customComp
4       c:/temp/file1.c bar()
5       c:/temp/file1.c baz()
3       c:/temp/file1.c foo()
10      c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn1()
8       c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn2()
9       c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn3()
2       c:/temp/file3.c ape()
1       c:/temp/file3.c chimp()
7       c:/temp/sub/file3.c     file3Fn1()
6       c:/temp/sub/file3.c     file3Fn2()
```

Comment: Off-topic: If you add `#include <vector>` and a `const` specifier to the `std::formatter<...>::format` method, your code compiles with gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/xM1daf1P4

Answer (score 1):

Your projection use is wrong, you sort them by path that way. Its purpose is to take an argument and return the basis for comparison, e.g. sorting by function name:

```
std::ranges::sort(copy, {},  // same as &MyStruct::functionName
                  [](MyStruct& s) ->decltype(s.functionName)& {
                       return s.functionName;
                  } );
```

Obviously, spaceship operator does not effect sort unless you use `std::identity` as a projection.

You can use an `std::tuple` projection.

```
std::ranges::sort( copy, {}, [](const MyStruct& s) { 
                        return std::tie(s.sourcePath, s.functionName); 
                   } );
```

This would use default `operator<=>` for `std::tuple`, not for your class. Obviousy, if you don't want this hassle with reference\copy issues the example above have and worrying about correct syntax of sort, you have to write a custom operator. In that case you can use a simpler version of `sort` function.

For printing as a tree after sorting, the file path should be treated as a range (`fs::path` can be of use, for it has iterators over its lexical elements, or your own equivalent), which would add depth to the loop in `print()` function.

Comment: thanks.  Although the projection is incorrect, I think the customCmp comparator works OK, is it not the same as your second projection example?   I'm new to projections, nice trick if the tie approach is equivalent to taking the address of a pair of members (most examples default the comparator and have a single field in the projection parameter) Also how would I put together a 2 level for loop using an outer loop that returns subranges and an inner loop that iterates over the subrange creating leaves in my tree structure - that is my real challenge.

Comment: @johnco3 it is, semantically. Your `customComp` is an equivalent of `less` if it was given those tuples. I'm not sure how  creating a tree, essentially a graph data structure, from a vector is relevant to the issue displayed, you didn't attempt to form a tree. Sorting lexographically is a good start unless you need a different rule to sort file names apart from folders. You have to analize filename (the path) to create and display one correctly.

Comment: @johnco3  if you want to do that as correctly formed paths , `#include <filesystem>`  `fs::path` may help with actual paths. Otherwise you have to do lexical analisis of path string yourself.

Comment: actually the std::filesystem::path fields order lexically just like std::strings - as you can see from my output.  BTW you are correct, I did not attempt to create a tree - I indicated I was stumped there putting in what I think I need to do so via a pair of loops.  The real code I have to is QT based and it basically does a foreach (unique filename) { foreach (functame in the filename loop)}.  I have no idea how to split the outer and inner loops using ranges.

Comment: my feeble implenentation which doesn't work was : copy |= ranges::actions::sort(customComp); for (const auto& next : ranges::views::filter(copy, [&](auto&& probe){ return (probe.sourceFile == sourcePath); })) {sourceNode->appendRow(new QStandardItem(next.function.c_str()));} coverageNode->appendRow(sourceNode);  (where copy is a copy of a similar vector of MyStructs)

Comment: @johnco3 what I meant that `begin()` and `end()` for `fs::path` are different from `std::string`, its iterator goes through elements of directory tree, not through characters. I'm not sure why think that ranges would be useful here. And if you think of folders as a file that can contain files, you end up with a collection of strings (names) each starting with root and ending with a function name. As you already sorted those collections, then all you have do ident appropriately while printing only the name of that nested level (kind of recursing through tree)

Answer (score 1):

This is a lengthy answer, because it contains four different approaches, each with its pros and cons.

## Using an `std::map` instead of ranges

From what I understand you want, a simple `std::map` would suffice:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <map>

using MyStruct = struct MyStruct {
    unsigned id;
    std::filesystem::path sourcePath;
    std::string functionName;
    auto operator<=>(const MyStruct&) const = default;
};

std::vector<MyStruct> structs{
    {1, "c:/temp/file3.c", "chimp()"},
    {2, "c:/temp/file3.c", "ape()"},
    {3, "c:/temp/file1.c", "foo()"},
    {4, "c:/temp/file1.c", "bar()"},
    {5, "c:/temp/file1.c", "baz()"},
    {6, "c:/temp/sub/file3.c", "file3Fn2()"},
    {7, "c:/temp/sub/file3.c", "file3Fn1()"},
    {8, "c:/temp/file2.c", "file2Fn2()"},
    {9, "c:/temp/file2.c", "file2Fn3()"},
    {10, "c:/temp/file2.c", "file2Fn1()"},
};

using Map = std::map<std::filesystem::path, std::vector<std::string>>;

int
main() {

    auto copy = structs;
    
    // sort by functionName
    std::ranges::sort(copy, std::less{}, [](auto const& s){ return s.functionName; });

    Map map;
    for (auto const& s : copy) {
        map[s.sourcePath].push_back(s.functionName);
    }

    for (auto const& [file, functions] : map) {
        std::cout << file << ":\t";
        int n{0};
        for (auto const& fun : functions) {
            std::cout << fun << (++n == functions.size()? "\n" : ", ");
        };
    }
}
```

Output:

```
c:/temp/file1.c:    bar(), baz(), foo()
c:/temp/file2.c:    file2Fn1(), file2Fn2(), file2Fn3()
c:/temp/file3.c:    ape(), chimp()
c:/temp/sub/file3.c:    file3Fn1(), file3Fn2()
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6P498sTGM

---

## Using ranges

Say you want to use ranges anyway, for composability and lazy evaluation. Then you have several options.

### Using `std::ranges::unique`

After sorting the input range, you can filter unique entries based on the sourcePath using `std::ranges::unique`. Then you can transform every entry in the unique range to the range of function names using `std::ranges::equal_range`:

```cpp
// sort first by sourcePath, then by functionName
auto copy = structs;
std::ranges::sort(copy, std::ranges::less{}, [](auto const& s){ return std::tie(s.sourcePath, s.functionName); });

// create a second copy which contains only the first element for each sourcePath
auto sorted = copy;
auto const ret = std::ranges::unique(sorted, std::ranges::equal_to{}, &MyStruct::sourcePath);
sorted.erase(ret.begin(), ret.end());
print("unique", sorted);

// transform each entry in the unique range to the list of functions
auto outer = sorted | 
    std::views::transform(
        [&copy](auto const& s){ 
            return std::ranges::equal_range(
                copy, 
                s, 
                [](auto const& l, auto const& r){ return l.sourcePath < r.sourcePath; }
            ); 
        }
    );

for (auto const& inner : outer)
    print("", inner);
```

```
unique
4   c:/temp/file1.c bar()
10  c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn1()
2   c:/temp/file3.c ape()
7   c:/temp/sub/file3.c file3Fn1()

4   c:/temp/file1.c bar()
5   c:/temp/file1.c baz()
3   c:/temp/file1.c foo()

10  c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn1()
8   c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn2()
9   c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn3()

2   c:/temp/file3.c ape()
1   c:/temp/file3.c chimp()

7   c:/temp/sub/file3.c file3Fn1()
6   c:/temp/sub/file3.c file3Fn2()
```

https://godbolt.org/z/888734r79

This way you get composability. You have lazyness in the inner loop, but `std::ranges::unique` is not lazy.

### Storing ranges in an `std::map`

Alternatively, you could create a map of sourcePaths, and instead of storing a container with function names, you store a lazy view created with `std::views::filter` as the values of the map:

```cpp
auto sorted_tree(auto const& rng)
{
    // this lambda returns a lambda, that checks if a MyStruct instance's sourcePath is equal to the input argument
    auto has_source_path = [](std::filesystem::path const& path){ 
        return [&](auto const& s){ 
            return s.sourcePath == path; 
        }; 
    };

    // store results in a map that maps strings to a std::ranges::filter_view
    using SubRangeType = std::ranges::filter_view<
        std::ranges::ref_view<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(rng)>>, 
        std::invoke_result_t<decltype(has_source_path), std::filesystem::path>
    >;
    using Map = std::map<std::filesystem::path, SubRangeType>;

    Map map;
    for (auto const& s : rng) {
        if (!map.contains(s.sourcePath)) {
            map.emplace(
                std::make_pair(
                    s.sourcePath, 
                    std::views::filter(rng, has_source_path(s.sourcePath))
                )
            );
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```cpp
auto copy = structs;

// optional: Only if you want the function names to be alphabetical
std::ranges::sort(copy, std::ranges::less{}, &MyStruct::functionName);

for (auto& [key, range] : sorted_tree(copy))
    print(key.generic_string(), range);
```

Output:

```
c:/temp/file1.c
4   c:/temp/file1.c bar()
5   c:/temp/file1.c baz()
3   c:/temp/file1.c foo()
c:/temp/file2.c
10  c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn1()
8   c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn2()
9   c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn3()
c:/temp/file3.c
2   c:/temp/file3.c ape()
1   c:/temp/file3.c chimp()
c:/temp/sub/file3.c
7   c:/temp/sub/file3.c file3Fn1()
6   c:/temp/sub/file3.c file3Fn2()
```

https://godbolt.org/z/G38WeG5hT

### Using `std::map` for a lazy version of `std::ranges::unique`

You could get a lazy version of `std::ranges::unique` by using `std::views::filter` together with a predicate, that stores a map of alreay visited sourcePaths.

```
auto lazy_unique() {

    struct unique_predicate
    {
        bool operator()(MyStruct const& s) {
            if (visited.contains(s.sourcePath)) {
                return false;
            }
            visited[s.sourcePath] = {};
            return true;
        }

        struct Empty {};
        std::unordered_map<std::filesystem::path, Empty> visited;
    };

    return std::views::filter(unique_predicate{});
};
```

You use it like this:

```cpp
// sort first by sourcePath, then by functionName
auto copy = structs;
std::ranges::sort(copy, std::ranges::less{}, [](auto const& s){ return std::tie(s.sourcePath, s.functionName); });   

// transform each entry in the unique range to the list of functions
auto outer = copy | lazy_unique() | 
    std::views::transform(
        [&copy](auto const& s){ 
            return std::ranges::equal_range(
                copy, 
                s, 
                [](auto const& l, auto const& r){ return l.sourcePath < r.sourcePath; }
            ); 
        }
    );

for (auto const& inner : outer) {
    print(inner.begin()->sourcePath.generic_string(), inner);
}
```

Output:

```
"c:/temp/file1.c"
4   c:/temp/file1.c bar()
5   c:/temp/file1.c baz()
3   c:/temp/file1.c foo()

"c:/temp/file2.c"
10  c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn1()
8   c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn2()
9   c:/temp/file2.c file2Fn3()

"c:/temp/file3.c"
2   c:/temp/file3.c ape()
1   c:/temp/file3.c chimp()

"c:/temp/sub/file3.c"
7   c:/temp/sub/file3.c file3Fn1()
6   c:/temp/sub/file3.c file3Fn2()
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8ds96dG7G

There is a problem with this approach though: the view adaptor returned by `unique_predicate` mutates a map when calling the predicate. As a consequence you cannot re-use the range: Iterating over it twice would return an invalid range in the second pass. Also you might encounter unintuitive compiler errors when you pass a const reference of the range around  *(e.g. to your `print` function)* because it is impossible to iterate over a const reference of the range since it needs to be mutated.

https://godbolt.org/z/edr1PGfPc

Comment: @jerorgbrech I wanted to learn more about using ranges, in particular their ability to lazy evaluate views and composability.  My table table may potentially be huge and ideally lazy sorting/iterating may be the way to go.  Thank you for your good answer, its also helpful.

Comment: Ok gotcha. Here is a possible solution that uses ranges: https://godbolt.org/z/o4Wzqe1T3. The problem I see with it is that `std::ranges::unique` is not lazy, so IMHO ranges just add to the complexity of your code and I have a hunch that the performance benefit is not worth the effort, if there is any at all. You could also mix the two approaches by storing a lazy range view in the `std::map` of sourcePaths: https://godbolt.org/z/9d84az1rn

Comment: And here is an even more lazy version using `std::views::filter` that doesn't require pre-sorting your list: https://godbolt.org/z/zzfvWKzer *((If you want the subranges of function names to be sorted alphabetically, you can still presort by the function name, but this is optional)*

Comment: @johnco3, I edited my anser to include the suggestions from my comments.